# To Get Text From A Locater Using Selenium IDE

Tags: selenium-ide

```
    <br>
    <br>
    To add new COT click on "Add New COT"
    <div class="stepandbutton">
        <div class="globalbuttoncell">
            <a class="buttonlink blockpage" onclick="javascript:addnewcot();" href="#">Add New COT</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    <input id="ComingFromForm" type="hidden" value="ComingFromForm" name="ComingFromForm">
    <input id="priorCOT" type="hidden" value="" name="priorCOT">
    <input id="rtncode" type="hidden" value="false" name="rtncode">
    <input id="refresh" type="hidden" value="NO" name="refresh">
    <input id="PDate" type="hidden" value="" name="PDate">
    <table>
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th align="center"> *Trade Class</th>
                <th align="center">*Description</th>
                <th>Category </th>
                <th>Exclude from AMP</th>
                <th>Exclude from AMP 5i</th>
                <th>Exclude from ASP</th>
                <th>Exclude from BP</th>
                <th>Exclude from NFAMP </th>
                <th>Exclude from Texas </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            <tr class="odd">
                <td align="center">
                    <input id="COT" class="data" type="text" value="" style="width:100px;" name="COT">
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <input id="Desc" class="data" type="text" value="" style="width:250px;" name="Desc">
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                    <select id="COTCategory" class="data small" name="COTCategory">
                </td>
                <td align="center">
                <td align="center">
                <td align="center">
                <td align="center">
                <td align="center">
                <td align="center">
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</form>
<br>
<br>
```

I need to verify only ""To add new COT click on "Add New COT""" which is in the 3rd line is present.I have tried with //br[contains(text(),"To add new COT click on "Add New COT"")]. But it showing error that locator is not found.Please suggest another ways to verify it.

Comment: The Method you've tried won't work because a <br> tag can't 'contain' anything. It doesn't have an opening and closing tag like others do.

You'll have a hard time checking just that part with the state of the code at the moment as it isn't enclosed in any tag at all (unless you count the <body> tag but that encompasses everything so wouldn't be the most accurate way of checking it). Your best bet would be to put that text in a <h> or <p> tag, or potentially put it in a div (could be it's own, or you could just move it into the existing one after it.) to give you a locator to find it with.

Answer (score 0):

This is ugly but would "work":

```
<tr>
    <td>verifyText</td>
    <td>//body</td>
    <td>*To add new COT click on "Add New COT"*</td>
</tr>
```

But as the commenter above mentions you don't want the br element. What you want to locate on is the element that you didn't provide that lives ABOVE the code you attached to. That would be best.